# Regex to determine currency format in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to write a jquery regex expression to determine if a string is in either of these formats `x,xxx.xx`, `x,xxx,xxx.xx` and `x,xxx,xxx,xxx.xx`.

Can anyone help? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use input mask search for digitalbush 's input mask it easy to manipulate

Comment: Verbalexpressions should be a good library to help you easily construct this regexp.

Comment: Why would anyone in his/her senses just vote down a question? If you cannot answer the question just leave it and go!!

Comment: @ShittuJosephOlugbenga you should always try to solve the problem yourself before coming to StackOverflow. If you have tried something, please tell what you have already tried in the question and we can help you with that. I believe the question got downvoted, because you had not stated how you had tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. If you're trying to convert theses values with grouped digits to an int or float use `replace()` to get rid of the commas and then parse them to the required type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went a step ahead and came up with this regex to match multiple formats of numbers which are ordered using `,`.

**Regex:** `\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?`

**Explanation:**

- `\d{1,3}` will match first group of digits, which may be 1,2 and 3. As ordering is implemented so no more than 3.
- `(,\d{3})*` will match the second group and so on. `*` matches one or more groups until `.` is found.
- `(\.\d{2})?` matches the decimal part( which I have made optional). You can make it compulsory simply by taking out `?`.

### <kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kU2xH2/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this - this just outputs the matches (if found), but you could do anything you want inside the conditional statement.

```js
var str = '1,234,567.88 1,234,567 9,876.54 1,123,234,345,456.67';

var splits = str.split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {

  if (splits[i].match(/(\d,)(\d{3},)*(\d{3}\.\d{2})/)) {
    $('#output').append(splits[i] + '<br>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output" )></div>
```